# Error while deploying Angular App (NodeJS) to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, bootstrap-4

I currently develop an `angular5` app, and need to deploy it to `Heroku`.
This app is served using `NodeJS`.

After logging into `Heroku`, I create new app by:

```
heroku create angular-vbnmc
```

and **it was successful**, now i could open `https://angular-vbnmc.herokuapp.com/` without problems, but still **the content is blank**, see picture below:
[image]

**Then** i deploy my app with following commands

```
git push heroku newFeatureBranch:master
```

Note: I didn't push my `master` branch but instead i push `newFeatureBranch` to remote `heroku`'s `master` branch

**and I got following error**

```
Counting objects: 219, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (208/208), done.
Writing objects: 100% (219/219), 122.63 KiB | 3.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 219 (delta 111), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.9.4
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.9.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        npm 5.6.0 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        bootstrap@4.0.0 /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/bootstrap
remote:        Installing any new modules (package.json)
remote:
remote:        > uws@0.14.5 install /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/uws
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0
remote:
remote:
remote:        > node-sass@4.7.2 install /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/install.js
remote:
remote:        Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/linux-x64-57_binding.node
remote:        Download complete
remote:        Binary saved to /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
remote:        Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.ShxWb/node-sass/4.7.2/linux-x64-57_binding.node
remote:
remote:        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
remote:        > node lib/post_install.js
remote:
remote:
remote:        > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node scripts/build.js
remote:
remote:        Binary found at /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
remote:        Testing binary
remote:        Binary is fine
remote:
remote:        > angular-vbnmc@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2
remote:        > ng build --prod
remote:
remote:
remote:        An error occured during the build:
remote:        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
remote:        ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
remote:        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_61c2abaea4d9525f4aeb3f08e81769a2/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! angular-vbnmc@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --prod`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the angular-vbnmc@0.0.0 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ShxWb/_logs/2018-03-06T04_54_08_334Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:        https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to angular-vbnmc.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/angular-vbnmc.git
 ! [remote rejected] 12-Deployment -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/angular-vbnmc.git'
```

For additional information, here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-vbnmc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.101",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Why** is this happening? and **how** to fix this error?